# Encrypting mapped network drives in Windows

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-server-2012, bitlocker

I have Win Server 2012 and the drives of one of the HDDs connected to it are mapped as network drives in a Windows 10 client. If I encrypt those drives using Bitlocker with the user account on the client, will it also be accessible for the admin account on the server? I want both users on the two machines to be able to access the encrypted content, how is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

For other readers; I realized that Bitlocker is basically a password/key-based encryption not tied to any Windows account; and after an encrypted drive is unlocked and opened, it behaves just like any other drives.